# Create a string based on the content within the first " and second "

Tags: powershell, split

Trying to generate a string based on the content of a file which contains multiple lines as follow:

```
"Name1""Path""Setting"
```

I need to figure out how to extract the content within the first `"` and second `"`, so the result should be `Name1`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `$line -replace '^[^"]*"([^"]+)".*', '$1'`

Answer (score 0):

A [`-split` operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) is probably simplest:

```
('"Name1""Path""Setting"' -split '"')[1]
```

Regex-based alternative via the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375):

```
'"Name1""Path""Setting"' -replace '^"(.*?)".*', '$1'
```

Both commands yield verbatim `Name1`.